# Pulling text and count of specific text from a different sheet using importrange

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheet containing a 'Notes' column and i would like to import the notes from those cells into another sheet and count how many times a certain word or phrase occurs.  I would like for the words/phrases to appear in the same cell separated by a comma.  So for example a cell in the import sheet would look like "1 Initiated, 3 Completed, 2 Needs more information,  1 Pending".  There is a set number of words/phrases which could be in the Notes column.

[Import From](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dnpQQX0YA-_BCxmcfpWYhkLupLPVarP_-C7RSKdpvJ0/edit?usp=sharing)
[Import To](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NkbXhj0JfCsQ68Zicuv33t2SNekJG7WdiEQchpHLF1E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hey I added links to both sheets in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A3:A"&COUNTA(A3:A)+2), 
 SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(""<>
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1dnpQQX0YA-_BCxmcfpWYhkLupLPVarP_-C7RSKdpvJ0", "Sheet1!A2:B"),
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1dnpQQX0YA-_BCxmcfpWYhkLupLPVarP_-C7RSKdpvJ0", "Sheet1!A2:B"),
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")&" "&INDEX(
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1dnpQQX0YA-_BCxmcfpWYhkLupLPVarP_-C7RSKdpvJ0", "Sheet1!A2:B"),
 "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,1)&",", )
 ,,99^99))), " , ", "♦"), ",$", ), "♦"), 2, 0), "Not Data"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I had to alter it a little to fit my actual sheet but works great thanks!